# Hitting maximum number of composite indexes in Firestore

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database in which I store a game's level score for various levels in a collection `scores`, like so:

```
player1: { levels: {
 1: { score: 2343, timestamp: t1 },
 2: { score: 434, timestamp: t2 },
},
player2: { levels: {
 1: { score: 23, timestamp: t3 },
 2: { score: 34, timestamp: t4 },
}
```

To get the top scores of any level X, I run the query:

```
collection('scores')
 .orderBy('levels.X.score')
 .orderBy('levels.X.timestamp', 'desc')
```

This requires to create a composite index for each level: `collection:score, levels.x.score asc, levels.x.timestamp desc`

A limit of 200 composite indexes means I'll only be able to create 200 levels in my database. 
Is there a way we can increases the limit, may be at some cost?
Or is there a way I can modify my database structure/query to prevent this limit from reaching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore limits can't be changed.

You will have to change the way your data is modeled.  Consider storing each score as a separate document in a collection that you can query.  So you would have:

```
/scores             // collection for all scores
  /some-id          // random id for this document with scores
    - playerId
    - level
    - score
    - timestamp
```

Then you can query across all the scores for a given level

```
firestore
    .collection('scores')
    .where('level', '==', X)
    .orderBy('score')
    .orderBy('timestamp')
```

Or something along those lines.  You will need just one composite index to support this query.

Comment: Makes sense. Seems like this will likely increase my read counts, but looks like the only option. Thanks Doug :)