# Firestore unused Index limitation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I have an application that uses Firebase Firestore as a database. Currently, I am out of indexes(composite) in the database. It reaches the limit to 200 and cant add more.

I'd manually deleted the index to some extent. Since my application is pretty large It is very difficult to manually find the unused index. Also, it takes time to recheck the same in multiple parts of the application.

I am looking for a solution. Either to identify the unused indexes in a better way than manually searching or an option to extend the limit of the index.

Comment: Can you share your database structure and the indexes required for your queries ?

Answer (score 0):

You may file a support ticket with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases), or [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to get the unused indexes, there is no automated way to do this.

Additionally, there is no way to increase the limit.

Changing the way your data is modeled so that you will need less composite indexes to support your query might also be an alternative as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55897597).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a solution. But we have removed a few indexes and tried for now. Also, this is something overhead for the developers who are building high-level applications using firestore.